# Prevent duplicate value while Insert or Update from DataSource

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Any idea how to do the validation of duplicate value while insert or update on below code structure ?

Where and how can i add on my validation to verify the duplicate record existed in the grid before the create or update events?

Thanks for the guide in advance.

```
    var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({        
        transport : {
            read : {
                url : 'readAttribute/',
                dataType : 'json',
                type : 'POST',
                complete : function(e) { }
            },
            create : {
                url : 'save/',
                dataType : 'json',
                type : 'post',
                contentType : 'application/json',
                complete : function(e) {
                    $('#dataGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                }
            },
            update : {
                url : 'update/',
                dataType : 'json',
                type : 'post',
                contentType : 'application/json',
                complete : function(e) {
                    $('#dataGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                }
            },
            destroy : {
                url : 'delete/',
                dataType : 'json',
                type : 'post',
                contentType : 'application/json',
                complete : function(e) {
                    $('#dataGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                }
            },
            parameterMap : function(options, operation) {
                if ((operation == 'create' || operation == 'update') && options.models) {
                    var valueData = options.models;
                    for (var i = 0; i < valueData.length; i++) {
                        valueData[i]['valTypeId'] = $("#valTypeDropDown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
                    }

                    var valFullData = {};
                    valFullData['val_data'] = valueData;
                    valFullData['val_type_id'] = $("#valTypeDropDown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();

                    return kendo.stringify(valFullData);
                }

                if (operation == 'destroy') {
                    return kendo.stringify(options.models);
                }

                if (operation == 'read') {
                    return {
                        valTypeId : $("#valTypeDropDown").data("kendoDropDownList").value()
                    };
                }
            }
        },
        batch : true,
        pageSize : com.babysister.client.Configuration.Constants.ListConfig.pageSize,
        sortable : true,
        scrollable : true,
        schema : {
            model : {
                id : "id",
                fields : {
                    id : {
                        type : "number"
                    },
                    name : {
                        type : "string",  
                        validation: { 
                            required: { message: "Name is required!" }
                        }
                    },
                    valTypeId : {
                        type : "number"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the `edit` event on the Kendo grid itself, as opposed to the `DataSource` you have shown.  There is sample code [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit) (for subscribing to the `edit` event).

Comment: Hi, edit event is do it before the data load right ? Any idea we can validate it after clicked on the create or update event before it send back to the server-side ?

Comment: From the docs: `Fired when the user edits or creates a data item.`  So you could use this to check the data that is entered in the grid to see if it is duplicate data, this has nothing to do with saving it back to the server.

Comment: ya.. but any idea that we can validate after user inserted/modified the value? From the link you share is before user insert the new value so that is not suitable for me to use to validate the duplicated value in the same column.... :(